# Is this a standard format for saving timezone rules?

Tags: datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

I am doing some "software archaeology" on [`python-dateutil`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) to fully document (and tighten up) the formats accepted by `dateutil.tz.tzstr`, and I have come across a strange timezone format that is obviously intended to be explicitly supported (link goes to the code):

[`# GMT0BST,3,0,30,3600,10,0,26,7200[,3600]`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/0a16bcb51c24dab5491110ef459d4c5b20807c3b/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L1380)

Just reading the code, I've figured out how it works. It starts out like a `TZ` environment variable:

- `GMT`: Standard time abbreviation
- `0`: Standard offset (in hours)
- `BST`: DST abbreviation

Then the rest is a comma-delimited list, broken into two parts:

- `3,0,30,3600`: DST->STD transition time specifier - month, week of month, day of week, seconds after midnight that the transition happens (note that when "week of month" is 0, the number following is actually the day of the month)
- `10,0,26,7200`: STD->DST transition time specifier - same as above
- `[,3600]`: If specified, this says how big the offset is during DST (default is 1 hour)

The [GNU `TZ` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) equivalent to this string is `GMT0BST,J89/1,J299/2`:

```
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> tz1 = tz.tzstr('GMT0BST,3,0,30,3600,10,0,26,7200')
>>> tz2 = tz.tzstr('GMT0BST,J89/1,J299/2')
>>> tz1 == tz2
True
```

Is this a standard timezone format somewhere, or just something that one of the earlier maintainers of `dateutil` added? It seems somewhat strange to add a custom time zone format that expresses exactly the same thing a GNU `TZ` variable does, but I only ever see "IANA database" and "POSIX TZ variable" as formats when searching for time zone rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a standard format of any kind (AFAIK).  Must be something internal to dateutil.

Note that this appears to be for `Europe/London`, and the correct POSIX string (for current years) would be `GMT0BST,M3.3.0/1,M10.5.0`

Comment: It's only used in the tests and examples AFAIK. Lord knows what the point was.

Comment: Also, I don't know why that rule was used in the example. My guess is that it's to demonstrate that it's easier in that format to specify a day-of-year since you can pass `month,0,day-of-month` rather than calculating Julian day of year. The `TZ` string is just the equivalent of the string in the documentation, not an actual representation of the UK zone.